# SED or AWK extract between string to end of line leave only first result found

Tags: awk, sed, extract

Trying to write an email processor extracting some data from email (dovecot/postfix based), so file located in

```
/home/moderator/Maildir/cur/1619183102.V97eI6001a560M865218.example.com:2,S
```

let's say

```
/home/moderator/Maildir/cur/file
```

Email file text contains text and HTML

```
Subject: New user
New user created 
User name:Billy Jean
<html><head><title>New user</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>New user created</p>
User name:Billy Jean<br>
</body>
```

The task is to extract exactly user name Billy Jean between

```
User name:
```

and end of line

but leave only first instance to avoid duplicates (ignore HTML line `User name:Billy Jean<br>`)

Already tested some variants from StackOverFlow like

```
awk '/^User name:/{print $NF}' /home/moderator/Maildir/cur/file
```

but it does not give a necessary result and does not correspond the exact matter of my question.

Thx for any ideas to try,

Comment: Try using: `awk '/^User name:/{print $NF;exit}' /home/moderator/Maildir/cur/file` once? To print only very 1st occurrence of match.

Comment: very close ! but it gives result Jean not Billy Jean

Comment: Try: `awk -F':' '/^User name:/{print $NF;exit}' /home/moderator/Maildir/cur/file` then.

Comment: YES ! Please post your answer I can mark as ANSWER to the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Look for string which you want to search and exit on its first existence after printing needed value.

```
awk -F':' '/^User name:/{print $NF;exit}' /home/moderator/Maildir/cur/file
```

***Bonus solution:*** In case your `awk` program has more things to handle and we can't get out of program without doing all stuff, then add a simple condition check with print so that it prints only very first occurrence of string.

```
awk -F':' '/^User name:/ && ++count==1{print $NF} {your rest of code here....}' /home/moderator/Maildir/cur/file
```

Answer (score 2):

Another using `match` and `substr`:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/^User name: */){print substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH);exit}' file
```

Output:

```
Billy Jean
```

Explaied:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/^User name: */) {   # regex to match
    print substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)  # print everything after match
    exit                             # exit after first match (or nextfile)
}' file
```

Also, you should probably consider some exit mechanism before the content part if `User name:` is not set, `/^<html>/{exit}` in the sample case.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '/^User name:/!d;s///;q' file
```

```
awk 'sub(/^User name:/,"") {print; exit}' file
```

or

```
sed -n '/^</q;/^User name:/!d;s///;p;q' file
```

```
awk 'f = sub(/^User name:/,""); f || /^</ {exit}' file
```